# Is it possible to have 2 different SpeechRecognizers working at the same time?

Tags: android, speech-recognition

When a `SpeechRecognizer` is processing an input sound, it takes a moment to be responsive again. I am intending to start a second `SpeechRecognizer` right when the first one calls `onEndOfSpeech()` to be responsive all the time but I am getting `ERROR_RECOGNIZER_BUSY`. I might be doing something wrong or it's just that only one `SpeechRecognizer` can be working at a time.

Does anyone knows if this is possible?

By the way, the speech recognizers I created are services, so there is no GUI.

Comment: It is possible with [CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid). Actually if you need a fast response it's a way better solution.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, I do agree CMUSphinx would be faster but in my experience it is not as accurate as google's. Do you know a way to improve Sphinx's accuracy?

Comment: CMUSphinx must be more accurate than google. If you want to debug accuracy issues you need to provide a test set of the samples you are trying to recognize. They are stored on sdcard in raw files as specified in pocketsphinx demo sources.